# how can I change the message "Password doesn't match confirmation"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i know that in config/en.yml I can change the message "this email is already been taken" changing the en.yml file :

en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        taken: "este mail ya sido utilizado"

but how can I change the message "Password doesn't match confirmation" I tried with password_confirmation and other combinations but don't works! 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those error messages belong to [activerecord](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/locale/en.yml).

Just create a new language file with that structure and replace what you need.

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    messages:
      confirmation: "does not match"
```

You shouldn't change en.yml as that is for english language strings.  You should make a new one for the language you require.  You can read about i18n at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: What if you want to change the first word. E.g. make the message "Passwords don't match," instead of "Password doesn't match"  ... Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4.0.2, I found this string with:

```
I18n.translate("errors.messages.confirmation")
  => "doesn't match %{attribute}"
```

I then modified it by putting this in my locale file:

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      confirmation: "%{attribute}s don't match - please check"
```